# SQL Server Data type change from Numeric(7,3) to Varchar(20)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a field (dose_str) that needs to be changed from  Numeric(7,3) to Varchar(20). I would like to know if there will be a need to change the query below (especially this portion **SELECT (convert(varchar,cast(Prot_det.dose_str as float))** ) in the code of my application.

```
myCommand.CommandText = "
  SELECT (convert(varchar,cast(Prot_det.dose_str as float)) + ' ' 
    + dose_unit + ' ' + dose_form_comment + ' ' + dose_mult) as Dose_str
  from 
    Prot_det, 
    dosage_form 
  where 
    Protocol_num = '" & lblProtocol.Text & "' and 
    nsc_num = " & lstNSC.SelectedValue & " and 
    prot_det.dose_form = dosage_form.dose_form"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the datatype of the column, you will be able to change this:

```
(convert(varchar,cast(Prot_det.dose_str as float))
```

to this:

```
(Prot_det.dose_str)
```

And I would recommend that you do.

Comment: No other part of the query needs to change.

Comment: I meant to say this line of code. I would also remove the toString at Eval("Dose_Str").toString:                                                                                            `<td><asp:Label ID="lblDosageStrength" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("Dose_Str").toString() + " " + Eval("Dose_Unit") + " " + Eval("Dose_Form_comment") + " " + Eval("Dose_Mult")) %>'></asp:Label></td>`

Comment: The .toString() isn't going to hurt anything by being there, so you don't have to remove it, but you probably can if you want.